# Are there any unconventional standards for ERC20 tokens on Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

My question is pretty straightforward: is there anything unconventional that most of erc20 tokens have in common that I should be concerned of? For example, USDT token is `Upgradable`, but I doubt it's conventional. If I simply deploy an erc20 token with contract body like this:

```
contract SomeToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("TKN", "Some Token") {}
}
```

is it sufficient for it to become a cryptocurrency just as USDT or any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it sufficient for it to become a cryptocurrency just as USDT or any other?

Yes

Comment: Any kind of source, or is it really straightforward?

Comment: Yes, it is that straightforward.